# CPDistributedMessagingCenter not working ios7

Tags: ios, notifications, messaging, jailbreak

I am fairly new to jailbreak iOS development and had a question. I am trying to send a message between two processes(MobileSafari to SpringBoard) and am having a problem, the reciever function in SpringBoard is never called! So far in SpringBoard I have this:

```
    -(void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(id)arg1{

            %orig(arg1);

            //register for notifications
            CPDistributedMessagingCenter *messagingCenter = [CPDistributedMessagingCenter centerNamed:@"com.magnusdevelopment.flow"];
            [messagingCenter runServerOnCurrentThread];
            [messagingCenter registerForMessageName:@"updateWallpaper" target:self selector:@selector(handleMessageNamed:withUserInfo:)];
            [messagingCenter registerForMessageName:@"updateScalingMode" target:self selector:@selector(handleMessageNamed:withUserInfo:)];
            [messagingCenter registerForMessageName:@"downloadWallpaper" target:self selector:@selector(handleMessageNamed:withUserInfo:)];
            UIAlertView *testAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Yo!" message:@"registered" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
            [testAlert show];
    }
}
    %new
    -(NSDictionary *)handleMessageNamed:(NSString *)name withUserInfo:(NSDictionary *)userInfo{

        UIAlertView *testAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Yo!" message:@"2" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [testAlert show];
        if([name isEqualToString:@"updateWallpaper"]){

            //get info for wallpaper
            NSString *wallpaperImagePath = [userInfo objectForKey:@"WALLPAPER_PATH"];
            int option = [[userInfo objectForKey:@"OPTION"] intValue];
            BOOL retValue = setWallpaperImage(wallpaperImagePath, option);

            //return the dictionary
            NSMutableDictionary *replyDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
            [replyDict setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%hhd",retValue] forKey:@"RETURN_VALUE"];
            return replyDict;

        }else if([name isEqualToString:@"updateScalingMode"]){

            //get info from dictionary
            int option = [[userInfo objectForKey:@"OPTION"] intValue];
            NSString *scalingMode = [userInfo objectForKey:@"SCALING_MODE"];

            //set wallpaper scaling mode
            setWallpaperScalingMode(scalingMode,option);

        }//end if

        return nil;
    }//end method
```

and when a button is pressed in MobileSafari I call this code:

```
NSString *option = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",wallpaperOption];
        NSDictionary *infoDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: wallpaperPath, @"WALLPAPER_PATH", option, @"OPTION", nil];
        CPDistributedMessagingCenter *messagingCenter = [CPDistributedMessagingCenter centerNamed:@"com.magnusdevelopment.flow"];
        [messagingCenter sendMessageAndReceiveReplyName:@"downloadWallpaper" userInfo:infoDict];
        UIAlertView *testAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Yo!" message:@"sent" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [testAlert show];
```

I get the alert "registered" whenever SpringBoard starts up and then when I press the button I get the message "sent". The only thing that isn't called is the function handleMessageNamed:withUserInfo:

Why isn't this working?

Thanks!

Comment: Try sending notifications without user info. Distributed notification center often is restricted in sandboxed apps - you can send notifications but without user info. Safari is sandboxed and your notifications are probably ignored because of the user info.

Comment: That didn't work. Any other ideas?

Comment: I am also open to other ways of sending a message from MobileSafari to SpringBoard.

Comment: Looks like safari sandbox is even more strict. There is always darwin notifications, they work everywhere but doesn't support user info. You could try `CFNotificationCenterGetDistributedCenter` with and without user info (pass nil). Also, check the console when you use `CPDistributedMessagingCenter`. There should be messages saying that sandbox denied your calls.

Comment: Can you give an example or a link to some code of how to use Darwin notifications? Googling it doesn't turn up anything... Thanks for all the help! :)

Comment: It's a public API https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/corefoundation/Reference/CFNotificationCenterRef/Reference/reference.html Shouldn't be hard to find sample code.

Comment: It worked, thanks! If you add this as the answer I will accept it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try darwin notifications https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/corefoundation/Reference/CFNotificationCenterRef/Reference/reference.html It's a public API, shouldn't be hard to find sample code.

Answer (score 2):

If you [look at this document entitled "Updating extensions for iOS 7](http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/Updating_extensions_for_iOS_7), it looks there **are** problems using `CPDistributedMessagingCenter` on iOS 7, but Ryan Petrich has published a library that may help you work around them:

> ### Inter-process communication
>
> CPDistributedMessagingCenter, XPC and other IPC methods built on top
> of bootstrap registered mach services don't work; you get deny lookup
> in the Xcode console.
>
> **Workaround**: 
>  rpetrich has built a workaround called RocketBootstrap: "One common way processes communicate with each other
> on iOS and OS X is through a messaging system called mach ports. Each
> port is a channel that can either receive or send messages. There is a
> central registration system for these ports called bootstrap, where
> ports can be registered and accessed by a service name assigned to
> them. Recent versions of iOS restrict which names a process can
> access—MobileMail, MobileSafari and App Store apps are only allowed to
> access a very specific set of services that come with iOS.
> RocketBootstrap adds a secondary lookup service that doesn't restrict
> which processes can access which services."